# Trace queries sent to PostgreSQL by Play! framework

Tags: postgresql, profiling, postgresql-9.2

I want to log the data (sql requests, in fact) going between my Play and Postgresql 9.2. In MS Server Management Studio there is a "built-in tool" - profile which is very convenient. I use PgAdmin 3 but I didn't find such a tool in it.

Is there any standard one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `postgresql.conf` set `log_statement = all`, adjust `log_line_prefix` if you want more details about the client.

You may also want CSV logging so you can easily analyze it - including loading it into a table with `COPY`. See [the documentation for CSV logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG).

For more details on log configuration, including things like logging long running statements, see [the documentation on log configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html).

You don't have to set these options globally; you can `ALTER USER my_play_user SET ...` or `ALTER DATABASE my_play_database SET ...` to make most of them local to a particular user or database.

The Play! framework also has features that enable logging of SQL it sends to PostgreSQL, which may also be handy.

For finer grained profiling/tracing, look at the `auto_explain` module, `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_stat_plans`.